# How to replace only selected visual block not the line in Vim

Tags: vim

Let's suppose I have the text.

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Then I select a `visual block` from 5 to 9.

```
        |-------| Select visual block          
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Run replace command `:'<,'>s/ /, /g`.

I expected the below.

```
1 2 3 4 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
```

However, the real result was

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
```

Replace command seems to apply to the whole line where the `visual block` is selected not only the block.

Is there any way for replace command to apply to only selected `visual block`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In my opinion this behavior is a bug in vim. You can work around it like this:

```
:'<,'>s/\%V \%V/, /g
```

`\%V` only matches within the current visual area.

Comment: Not a bug, but a peculiarity of Ex command ranges. Wray Zheng's answer explains it.

Comment: Could there be a way to redefine 's' so \%V is always implicit?  It might not be considered a bug, but the definition of 's' should be change and not be limited to line oriented.  Very few people would want a search and replace to occur on a per line basis when a visual block is selected.

Answer (score 3):

Just to clarify a thing: `:s` command is **linewise**, which means it will perform substitutions on **lines** in range.

By the way, single quote followed by position symbol such as `'<` means the starting **line** of visual block. And `'a` means the **line** you mark with `ma` command.

If you want to refer to the precise position (column), you need to use ` rather than `'` before position symbol. For example, you can move to the starting position (the actual column) of recently selected visual block by `<, where `'<` can only move to the beginning of that line. But this won't work in `:s` command, as mentioned above substitute command is linewise.

Comment: you should also note that `\`<` wont work in the substitute command.